# How to obtain an object specific value?

Tags: javascript, object, handsontable

I get the following object from a php file:

```
[
 {"val1":"A","val2":"TA","val3":"5"}, 
 {"val1":"A","val2":"TB","val3":"3"}, 
 {"val1":"A","val2":"TC","val3":"2"}
]
```

I tried doing things like:

```
{label: {data:'val1'} }

{label: {data:'val1'[0]} }

{label: {data:['val1'][0]} }
```

But so far no luck to obtain the value I want.

This is the part of my code that deals with the data from the object:

```
var containerD1 = document.getElementById('tabD1');
var hotD1 = new Handsontable(containerD1, {
  rowHeaders: true,
  colHeaders: true,
  columns: [
    {type:'text', data: 'val2', readOnly:true},
    {type:'text', data: 'val3', readOnly:true},
  ],
  nestedHeaders: [
    [{label: {data:'val1'}, colspan: 2}],
    ['Val2','Val3']
  ]
  });
```

Since val1 value is dynamic, I can't set it as I have done for val2 and val3

So what I want to achieve is obtaining the value from val1 to be able to use it in the nestedHeaders part as the title for my table, since this value is repeated trough my object, it doesn't matter from which one I take it.

So far what I obtain is a table like this

```
+------+------+
|   object    |
+------+------+
| val2 | val3 |
+------+------+
| TA   |    5 |
| TB   |    3 |
| TC   |    1 |
+------+------+
```

In the object part, in my table it says this [object Object].
So I'm guessing it's actually being read as an object instead of the value I want.

And I'm trying to get something like this:

```
+------+------+
|      A      |
+------+------+
| val2 | val3 |
+------+------+
| TA   |    5 |
| TB   |    3 |
| TC   |    1 |
+------+------+
```

Comment: If you set up a complete code snippet that we can run you're more likely to get a good answer!

Comment: Are you sure that the php file/endpoint is returning proper JSON? You can check by doing a typeof or parse it out JSON.parse()

Comment: in my php file i use the following code to send my object: $myJSON = json_encode($arrayTop); echo $myJSON; , this sends out the object but without a name, just the pure object

Answer (score 0):

### Code snippet to get the value of **val1**

{ label: { data: data[0].val1 } }

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand you correctly. If you want to obtain the value of `val1` property in your objects, I would do this (since you say it doesn't matter from which element of the array you take it):

```
    const data = [
 {"val1":"A","val2":"TA","val3":"5"}, 
 {"val1":"A","val2":"TB","val3":"3"}, 
 {"val1":"A","val2":"TC","val3":"2"}
]

console.log(data[0]["val1"])
```

Alternatively, you could write:
`console.log(data[0].val1)` instead of the last line of code.

Comment: Since my object is not defined like that, I can't use it that way. It's actually just defined with the values in my network tab

Comment: that was the format for the data you posted. can you post the data in the format you have @carlos.p?

Comment: I mean, thats the data itself, it just not declared as a const or any kind of variable